# skip dirty checking for some specific element into ng-form

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have an ng-form and it has five input fields, each input field contains ng-model directive, now my need is the 4th number input field will not fire for dirty checking, how can I solve this?

**Problem:** no need dirty checking for some specific element into form.

Comment: Show some code. Doing dirty check is your implementation, you can skip it if required which verification.

Comment: @Chandermani, Hi, see my plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/FS3soxcBIzxlZNxiYN1H?p=preview, here I want to skip dirty checking into name field

Comment: Remove `required` attribute from name field. So no validation

Comment: @Chandermani, ok but when i write something into name filed, that time from dirty is enabled, I mean to say that if I write something into name filed no need dirty checking, I want to skip dirty checking for this field.

Comment: @Chandermani, required is out. but does not work. from dirty is enabled.

Comment: I don't think that is possible,as this is the default behaviour. What you can do it to apply ng-change directive to input and in the function then call `$setPristine()` on the model controller.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Override the `$setDirty` method defined on `ngModelController` for the name field.

Create a directive `no-dirty`.

```
validationApp.directive('noDirty', function () {
  return {
    require: 'ngModel',
    link: function (scope, element, attrs, ngModelCtrl) {
      // override the $setDirty method on ngModelController
      ngModelCtrl.$setDirty = angular.noop;
    }
  }
})
```

Use this directive in markup

```
<input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" ng-model="user.name" required="" no-dirty/>
```

[Working Plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/UwuJBpMIo6apMGj17fH0?p=preview)